# PHP cURL GET Request to REST API not returning anything

Tags: php, rest, api, get

I'm trying to use the [UMLS Search REST API](https://documentation.uts.nlm.nih.gov/rest/search/). I successfully retrieved the TGT and The ST. However, when trying to do a search as mentioned in the documentations, I got no response at all.
Here's my code:

```
<?php
$service_ticket='xxx' //ST retrieve earlier
$cURLConnection = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_URL,"https://uts-ws.nlm.nih.gov/rest/search/current");
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//avoid unable to get local issuer certificate
 $values = array(
    'ticket' => $service_ticket,
    'string' => 'C0162565'
    );
$params = http_build_query($values);
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params); 
$qresult = curl_exec($cURLConnection);
curl_close($cURLConnection);
$jsonArrayResponse = json_decode($qresult,true);
print_r($jsonArrayResponse);
?>
```

Comment: Try `var_dump($qresult)` to see what the raw result of the curl operation. If it's false have a look here for viewing curl errors: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: I did, it turned out that it's a SSL problem. When I try to avoid it using 
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
The result is: HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported?

Comment: As a hint: you might want to avoid writing all such stuff on your own. Isn't there any SDK provided directly by that API? Even if not, try to use Guzzle instead of cURL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API expects a GET request, but using `curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);` is changing the request type to POST. removing this command and adding the parameters directly to the URL fixes the problem.